# Is this answer acceptable?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, link-only-answers

I was browsing new questions when [I came across this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27260761/c-make-lower-function?noredirect=1#comment42994710_27260761) one.

Before I typed up my answer to the question, this answer popped up:

http://puu.sh/deFuw/e8e147dfb2.png

Whilst this answer answers the question, I personally think that there should be slightly more ***meat*** in the answer, perhaps a code example or expansion of what the answerer has already written.

I attempted to edit the answer but found that I had nothing to edit to satisfy the 10 character minimum edit-floor so potentially this answer can be classed as 'low quality'.

I raised a custom moderator flag asking for clarification to whether this answer is good enough, but I've got a feeling that the flag's going to be (probably rightly) declined as 'the community can handle this', so I thought I'd ask here on Meta.

Am I right that this answer isn't 'meaty enough', and can the answer be classed as 'low-quality'?
I'm slightly confused.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A post being of low quality does not merit a flag. Downvote, and move on. You can't force the OP to improve.

If the answer was "I like dogs" or "Check out this link!" then it wouldn't be an answer and would be worthy of deletion (NAA flag). I wouldn't say the post remotely merits a VLQ flag, it is poor, but not deletion-worthy poor.

The flag will likely be declined as you said. There isn't really anything for a mod to do to that post.

Comment: "A post being of low quality does not merit a flag" It's kind of ironic, then, that if the answer were flagged it would end up in the "*Low Quality* Posts" review queue.

Comment: @AndrewMedico It should probably be called the "Very Low Quality Posts" queue. In any case, that post wouldn't match my description of "Very low quality".

Comment: @BradleyDotNET The flag was actually marked as 'helpful: http://puu.sh/dfcSa/11ddc92677.png. No idea if the moderator saw this Meta question or not.

Comment: @cybermonkey Nothing was done to the post, so maybe the moderator was simply agreeing with you. Its hard to say unless they comment here. I *am* surprised it was marked helpful.